# Gulp JS Build does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, gulp

What is wrong with this html code:

```
<!-- build:js js/main.min.js -->
    <script src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/pages/orders.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/js/main.js')
        .pipe(through2.obj(function(file, enc, next) {
            browserify({
                entries: file.path,
                debug: isDevelopment
            }).bundle(function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                file.contents = res;
                next(null, file);
            });
        }))
        .on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
        .pipe($.if(isDevelopment, $.sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: true
        })))
        .pipe($.if(isDevelopment, $.sourcemaps.write('.')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/js'));
});
```

Because I'm always getting only main.js inside main.min.js file, instead of main.js and orders.js merged and minified together into main.min.js

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is in your code itself. You need to change the second line to

```
return gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
```